# How to serve AASA file (for deep links) with a react create app?

Tags: react-native, expo, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, aasa

I have a simple react create app where I want to host the AASA file so I can have deep links to my native app. Im using expo and based on their documentation, I only have to put that file into my public folder. It does not work.
The file is not being rendered and I get the err:

> Your file's 'content-type' header was not found or was not recognized.

Ive been reading and researching on how to do it and the only solution I saw included using Nginx or firebase. My website is really just a simple landingpage for my app and I wonder is there any OTHER solution?